# leaflet map not loading properly

Tags: jquery, dictionary, leaflet

I use `leaflet` map in my web service but it is not loading properly. The bottom portion is not loading in fact.

How to solve it? I just use this code:

```
var latlng = new L.LatLng(50.5, 30.51);

var map = new L.Map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 15, layers: [cloudmade]});

var markers = new L.FeatureGroup();

var london = new L.LatLng(51.505, -0.09); // geographical point (Longitude and Latitude)  
map.setView(london, 13).addLayer(cloudmade);
```

Answer (score 4):

> Error: cloudmade is not defined

Where do you want to get your maps from? You have to define a URL as in this example: [Leaflet Quick Start Guide](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/quick-start.html).

Insert this line before using the variable `cloudmade` (after obtaining your own key).

```
var cloudmade = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/YOUR-API-KEY/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be one of the following issues:

- Initialising the map before the DOM is ready.
- The cloudmade variable for the TileLayer not being set correctly.

The following solution will initialise the map when the element with ID 'map' is available (This is achieved by placing the script at the bottom of the page. Alternatively you could use jQuery). This will also set the cloudmade variable to use MapQuest OpenStreetMap tiles.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Leaflet test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet.js"></script>
        <link href="leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.ie.css" />
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width:640px;height:480px"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg';
            var subDomains = ['otile1','otile2','otile3','otile4'];
            var cloudmadeAttrib = 'Data, imagery and map information provided by <a href="http://open.mapquest.co.uk" target="_blank">MapQuest</a>, <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> and contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/" target="_blank">CC-BY-SA</a>';
            var cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: cloudmadeAttrib, subdomains: subDomains});

            var london = new L.LatLng(51.505, -0.09);

            var map = new L.Map('map', {center: london, zoom: 13, layers : [cloudmade]});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd also suggest that you look over the first examples at the [Leaflet - Quick Start Guide](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/quick-start.html) as they explain what each line is doing and offer a solution for using a CloudMade tile layer.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to care about details of leaflet.js, you might want to look at this
https://github.com/hamsterbacke23/qleaflet